# Weak convergence problem without a condition

Tags: weak-convergence

I have a problem that I am not sure so I need your help.
If we have ${X_n} \Rightarrow X$ and $P(X=0)=0$ then we can show $X_n^{-1} \Rightarrow X^{-1}$ ($0^{-1}$ is defined as $0$) but can we prove it without the condition $P(X=0)=0$? Any comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly false without the condition $P(X=0)=0$. Take $X_n =\frac 1 n, X=0$ for a counter-example.

Comment: So you mean without this condition, ${X_n}$ will never converge weakly to $X=0$ even if $n$ go to infinity? Can you explain a bit more detail? Thank you very much!

Comment: Just think of the corresponding question for sequences of real numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I will check it.